# Converting a has_one association to has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Wondering about a relationship I have and not sure wheter this is due to cause some issues in the future.

I have the following relationships with Users and Leases.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :lease, foreign_key: "tenant_id"
  has_many :leases, foreign_key: "landlord_id"
end
```

and

```rb
class Lease < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :landlord, class_name: "User"
end
```

and I'm trying to convert the relationship with the tenant and the lease to has_many, but I don't know how to approach this the right way.

I got this to work with

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :leases_as_landlord, class_name: "Lease", foreign_key: "tenant_id"
  has_many :leases_as_tenant, class_name: "Lease", foreign_key: "landlord_id"
end
```

and

```rb
class Lease < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :leases_as_tenant
  belongs_to :landlord, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :leases_as_landlord
end
```

but I don't like calling `User.leases_as_landlord` and `User.leases_as_tenant`. What I would like to do is just call `User.leases` to return the leases in which the `User` is either the landlord or the tenant.

Comment: What if the landlord of one apartment is a tenant of another?

Comment: This functionality is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can add instance method:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :leases_as_landlord, class_name: "Lease", foreign_key: "tenant_id"
  has_many :leases_as_tenant, class_name: "Lease", foreign_key: "landlord_id"

  def leases
    leases_as_landlord.or(leases_as_tenant)
  end
end
```

It will also return `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` and you can chain other ActiveRecord method on it.

Also I would recommend to follow [Rails Convention](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e#relations-in-models) and name your `has_many` associations in the plural.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :landlord_leases, class_name: 'Lease', foreign_key: :tenant_id
  has_many :tenant_leases, class_name: 'Lease', foreign_key: :landlord_id

  def leases
    landlord_leases.or(tenant_leases)
  end
end
```

Comment: Using this and defining the method `leases` seems to break eager loading?

Comment: Can you provide code snippet how you use `leases` method with `eager_load`?